# Rails 3.2.14: assets not resolving

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an application on Rails 3.2.14. When I start it in production environment after precompiling assets. It does not resolve to assets as path generated by javascript_include_tag is /javascripts/application.js without any digest. Similar for css it generates /stylesheets instead of /assets

IT ALSO DOES NOT INCLUDE DIGEST

Here are snapshot from my production.rb

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
```

Comment: fyi in Production the URL should be /stylesheets and not /assets.  /assets is only for development.

Comment: Then how come `rake assets:precompile` generate assets folder combined with all assets in one folder?

Comment: Yes, that's a great question.

Comment: Maybe because that gets done before the files are placed in /public  Not sure.

Comment: So what the version of ```rails``` do you use? ```3.1.14``` or ```3.2.14```

Comment: @freemanoid Its mentioned in first line itself.

Comment: @ducktyped have you generate the assets like this ```RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUP=assets rake assets:precompile``` ?

Comment: @freemanoid: yes I did

Comment: @ducktyped: Did you upgrade your project to rails3.2.14 ? because in rails 3.2.14 rails automatically generates url for stylesheets and javascript as /assets/application-digest.(js|css)